# Unable to use the REST API services in Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher

Tags: json, oracle, rest, postman, bi-publisher

I am trying to call the REST API services in order to access a BIP report by using Postman tool. I am using various methods (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE) available over the Oracle documentation to get the relevant data from the server. But, only GET method (Get report definition, Get report sample data and Get XDO schema) are working fine and the rest are giving either of the following errors: 400 Bad Request or 415 Unsupported Media Type or 404 Not Found or 405 Method Not Allowed or Could not get any response.

I am using the same as in the images in the header section and body as well but still I am getting the error can you please suggest.

http://localhost:port/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports/Components%2FSampleReport/run

Body

[image]

Header

[image]

Comment: How did you make the Get work? I am trying to get sampleData but I am always getting 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `%2F` as encoding for '/' try `%252F`.

So, your URL would be

`http://localhost:port/xmlpserver/services/rest/v1/reports/Components%252FSampleReport/run`